# Disconnecting a gun peer

Tags: gun

What is the correct way to disconnect gun peers?
I can connect peers with:

```
Gun(['http://127.0.0.1:8080/gun','http://127.0.0.1:8081/gun'])
```

But cant disconnect again using

```
Gun(['http://127.0.0.1:8080/gun')
```

as peers will still both sync. In the last part of the video I couldn't disconnect the peers as both db's were still syncing.

On a different note the first part of the video shows problems with Chrome not updating however firefox works as it should.

[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yn1uNQmbqUw) and
[Source Code](https://gist.github.com/sothix/5dae106298c985f068c7a70ae305f5b2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@soth this is a good question. There is currently no standard way to disconnect from a peer. This should probably be added.

This is terrible. But here is a hacky solution for now:

```
var peers = gun.back('opt.peers');
Object.keys(peers).forEach(function(id){
    var peer = peers[id];
    peer.retry = 0;
    gun.on('bye', peer);
});
```

This will disconnect from all peers. If you only want one, filter by the ID which will probably be the URL.

Comment: Can i get the peer ID dynamically, Instead of hardcoding? Or can i close all connections in a loop?

Comment: You can iterate over the peers object using plain JS or `Gun.obj.map(peers, cb)` utility.